# Unable to find the document downloaded from google drive API, where is it?

Tags: java, google-drive-api

```
 OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
service.files().export(fileId, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

Comment: It's still in memory... You need to write the stream to a file

Comment: hello, what memory? like where is it on the pc, how do i open it?

Comment: can you please show me how? thank you in advance :)

Comment: It's not on your PC anywhere as a File... It's still a byte array  within the Java process.

Comment: oh ok... ive been stuck on this for days, can you please show me how to save it as a file on my pc? appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Use a different OutputStream](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-fileoutputstream-example/)

```
File file = new java.io.File("foo.docx");
try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
    // if file doesn't exists, then create it
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }
    service.files()
        .export(fileId, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
        .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream):
}
```

Comment: the error im getting now is: File in Class cannot be applied to given types, Required no arguments, found: string, reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Sounds like you defined your own File class... Updated the answer

Comment: never mind, it worked, without the new File() i just put the path.. THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: you just saved my life lol i gotta finish this project till wednesday